# Format date without translating text

Tags: localization, datetime

Is there a simple way to opt out of the translation that occurs when you format a date like this:

```
{{ expiry | date('D, d M Y H:i:s', 'GMT') }}
```

The problem is that I need this in english to create a valid date for my HTTP headers. But the site is in norwegian so days and months are translated, resulting in an invalid date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently - we should probably add a new 'translate' argument to that function which would let you opt out of it.

However Craft’s DateTime variables have a [`rfc1123()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/dates/DateTime#rfc1123-detail) function which can be used instead of the Twig `|date` filter, and its output won’t get automatically translated.

For reference, [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) defines the date/time specification recommended by [RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3) (which is the same as the one defined by [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5), just with 4-digit years).

```twig
{{ expiry.rfc1123() }}
```

Comment: Great. The date string doesn't look exactly like the date-header, but maybe both is allowed? "Date:Sun, 28 Sep 2014 15:14:58 GMT" vs "Expires:Monday, 29-Sep-14 15:14:58 UTC". Actually .rfc822() looks more like it, but doesn't output the name of the timezone, just the time diff.

Comment: @AndréElvan Sorry, while the RFC 850 specification should work, apparently it’s obsolete, and RFC 1123 is recommended. Just updated the answer.